# Need to Create a Tool with Location Search and Toggling of Separate Fusion Table Overlays

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have three separate Fusion Tables, each one of which contains shape files for various political districts (Congress, State Assembly & State Senate). What I am looking to do is create a tool, very similar to that of Derek Eder's demo (http://derekeder.com/searchable_map_template/demo/index.html) that would allow a user to find there address, and then could select ONE of the overlays (using radio buttons instead of the checkboxes on Derek's example) in order to see what district they are within.

From the various questions asked previously as well as the other examples I have looked at online, I was hadnt necessarily seen something that would have led me to believe that a code example was grabbing multiple table data, but rather just parsing specific data from within one large table.

I guess I am just looking for guidance on where to start. Can the tool I described be put together fairly easily with three separate tables or would the tables need to be combined? Also, I would need to keep a location marker of the address search showing and the same coordinates, zoom level preserved while switching between the various layers. In my mind I can imagine that latter point wouldnt be difficult with a single table, but i had some concerns about keeping that view in place when toggling between separate ones.

Any and all help anyone could offer would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't fully understand your requirement: the user has to enter an address and then has to select one of the layers (i.e. one of the three tables) "in order to see what district they are within"? I guess you want to determine that information in your tool, right? I guess a [Merged Table](http://support.google.com/fusiontables/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=171254) would be the easiest way to implement this.

Comment: Odi - Thanks for the response. Yes a person would type in their address, and it would show their location on the map. Then they could toggle between layer options to see one of the three district types they are contained within. Although I could certainly manage merging the tables into one if need be, I was also looking for any examples anyone might be able to point me at which may help me with getting started.

Answer (score 0):

I have pieces:

- Marker from geocoded address used to spatially search a table
  [Example 1](http://www.geocodezip.com/webknows_net_schoolboundarynewC.html) [Example 2](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_geocoder_PointInPolygon.html)
- Zoom to polygon resulting from querying a FusionTable (uses two tables) [Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/www_advocacy_ucla_edu_Assembly_MapC.html)

Unless there is something strange about your requirement that I missed in your post, it should be easily doable.